# ¿cúal es la sintaxis para hacer un casting de clase una generica? C#

Tags: c#, class, template, genericos, casting

¿Cómo se hace un casting de una clase gérica?

Estoy intentado lo siguiente pero no funciona. Este es el error que me está dando

*CS0119 C# 'Entity' es tipo, que no es válida en el contexto indicado*

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//DataBase: Es un tipo génerico
public class Entity<DataBase> : MonoBehaviour where DataBase : class
{
    [SerializeField] private DataBase dataBase;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//EnemyDataBase: Es un tipo específico
public class Enemy : Entity<EnemyDataBase>
{
    EnemyDataBase enemyDataBase;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//DataBase: Es un tipo génerico
public class State <DataBase> where DataBase : class
{
   protected Entity<DataBase> entity;

   Public method(Entity<DataBase> entity)
   {
   }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public class MyEnemy : Enemy
{
   State state;
   Public void Start()
   {
         state = new State();

         state.method( Entity<EnemyDataBase> this);      // --> asi no funciona
         state.method( (Entity)<EnemyDataBase> this);    // --> asi no funciona
         state.method( ((Entity)<EnemyDataBase>) this);  // --> asi no funciona
   }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: probaste con el operador `as` ?

Comment: No... estoy muy verde con C#... nunca he usado ese operador... voy a informarme para ver como funciona... Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que tu pregunta seria saber si tu objeto es del mismo tipo creado, pero se me pierde alguna informacion mental para darle una respuesta totalmente clara, entoncces disculpa si no le acierto. Tampoco veo donde estas creando el objeto que quieres hacer el cast sino que intentas pasarle la misma clase con `this` en lugar de un objeto concreto.

Si vos creas un Tipo Generico y luego queres saber si ese tipo creado es igual a otro podes usar dos operadores en c#, `is` y `as`

el operador `is` pregunta si esto de un cierto tipo, lo cual te devuelve un `true` o `false`;

El operador `as` intenta hacer el cast del objeto y si no puede te deja el objeto en `null` y no rompe tu app. Caso contrario pasaria si quieres hacer el cast asi: `(Enemy)MiObjetoCreado`;

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public class MyEnemy : Enemy
{
   State state;
   Public void Start()
   {
         state = new State();
         
           if(MiObjetoCreado is Entity<EnemyDataBase>)
           {
              state.method(MiObjetoCreado);      
           }
           
           var objetoNuevo = MiObjetoCreado as Entity<EnemyDataBase>;

           if(objetoNuevo != null)
           {
              state.method(MiObjetoCreado);  
           }
   }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Ramiro!! Al final lo hize usando "as" como me dijiste!! ... lo que en vez de hacerlo en los parametros de la función lo hice dentro de la función misma... (tenia que pasar el puntero "this" si o si porque ese era mi objeto concreto)!!  Muy apreciada tu ayuda!! Muchas gracias!! Saludos!!